# company asking to freeze their IT and communications in case of incident

Tags: legal

My second job is private income once in a while, I work for a small law firm. There are not many standards or formalities so most of the work is discussed in person or sometimes emails. I already have to keep the documentation with a lot of passwords of their email accounts and other websites and I am not happy about it. My role in their business is a consultant or a contractor for IT related issues.

Recently the owners approached me and asked for a favor: once something happens to the them like an incident or something else that they would not be available to continue operating, I need to freeze all their accounts, website, communications including mobile and emails. Then pass over all access passwords to the person they will designate.

I do not know how such scenario is even called in business. I also am a bit worried and not willing to accept their offer as it does not sound plausible. At the very least there should be formalities agreed in writing I believe, and I can only speculate why would they be worried all of a sudden. They either seem to have some trust for me or just want to use me easily. Maybe I should devise a strict contract between them and me and together with that to register a limited company, besides having my permanent work somewhere else.

Comment: What does "freeze" mean? Determining if it can be done at all starts with that, and is out of scope here....

Comment: means to login into accounts (emails, facebook, etc) and change passwords so no staff could use them, block mobile phone from taking calls, shut down the website, etc. I just dont want to be involved into something bad and be in trouble too. But technically can be done.

Comment: would "lockdown" be a better word - agreed, this is out of scope for here, though - very specific to IT and policy.

Comment: @user53220 "shut down the website, etc". -- If the owner says "shut down the website immediately", and that is your job, why do you think it would be bad to do it?

Comment: "Recently the owners approached me and asked for a favor: once something happens to the them like an incident or something else that they would not be available to continue operating, I need to freeze all their accounts, website, communications including mobile and emails. Then pass over all access passwords to the person they will designate." - first, clarify if this is a maneuver to evade the local laws.

Comment: I do not understand why is it off-topic, it is related to worry about workplace and fear of legal consequences and just looking for a way to move the right direction. I only can think of not phrasing this correctly, my apologies then. I was trying to make this a generic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the assets belong to them but you are the one maintaining/storing/controlling them, then this is perfectly reasonable. I have done this more than once, in joint venture situations, where one side is paying me and they own the assets and then it all starts to fall to bits and the other side is demanding access to things they don't own and haven't paid for.

And in situations where there is suspicion of foul play close to the top and records etc,. need to be kept safe. Or a disgruntled employee has gone off the rails and started doing things they shouldn't. In fact I have frozen clients assets on my own responsibility more than once when I have seen bad things being done and needed to stop them while trying to contact the bosses.

At the end of the day it's their assets, they can freeze them and hand over control any time and for (almost) any reason they want. Your major concern shouldn't be about doing it, it's not illegal, and if the police want access to the records and have a warrant, you give it to them. Your major concern should be getting paid to do it in that eventuality, because it's a bit of work by the sound of it.

Comment: Just be sure you have the instructions to do so in writing, and I'd recommend getting notarized signatures.